# The principle of binary representation of data types in Julia

Tags: julia

```
julia> type TestA
       a::Int32
       b::Int64
       end
julia> type TestB
       a::Int64
       b::Int64
       end

julia> sizeof(TestA),sizeof(TestB)
(16,16)
```

I am expeced that `sizeof(TestA)` will be 4+8=12.

---

I am curious about the principle behind the scenes.

Why `TestA` and `TestB` have the same size?

ps: http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/devdocs/object/ is a good material

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with Julia, but I'd suspect it's byte alignment.  For instance, if you define a `struct` in C or C++ that contains a `uint8_t` and a `uint32_t`, you'll find that it takes up 64 bytes of memory on most platforms unless you use directives to insist upon the sizes.

Comment: a workaround is to override Base.size: `size(x::TestA) = sizeof(x.a) + sizeof(x.b)` if you want

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think @DavidHoelzer is right, as the [documentation](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/devdocs/object/#object-allocation) says: `Note that all objects are allocated in multiples of 4 bytes and aligned to the platform pointer size.` . If you need packed structures, you can try: [StrPack](https://github.com/pao/StrPack.jl#strpack-structured-binary-stream-tools)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Byte alignment is the answer.  The documentation states that:

> Note that all objects are allocated in multiples of 4 bytes and aligned to the platform pointer size.

Comment: In general, Julia tries to match C struct alignment rules so that you can mirror C structs in Julia and pass value back and forth.